# Remplazar espacios por guion bajo en el nombre de las columnas?

Tags: sql

Buen dia

Estoy utilizando sql y Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de remplazar los espacios
en los nombres de las columnas por guiones bajo(_)

adjunto  imagen con nombre actual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan ayudar, Gracias

Ojo:La tabla que tengo son 32 columnas si pueda hacerlo en general estaria agradecido

Comment: ¿Reemplazar en la consulta como un ALIAS, o reemplazar permanentemente en la base de datos?

Comment: HOLA @aeportugal si se pudiera con un alias estaría mucho mejor

Comment: `select [Razon Social]  as Razon_Social` esto es lo único que se puede hacer en `sql`, cualquier otra cosa dependerá del motor de base de datos que uses, y no has especificado ninguno en las etiquetas, por favor agregalo.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho SI me funciono, como puedo marcar tu comentario como respuesta

Comment: @JoseLuisDeLaCruzMorales, si la respuesta te fue útil te agradecería que la marcaras como aceptada, un saludo

Answer (score 1):

En esta consulta obtienes los nombres de las columnas de una tabla y un esquema en especifico:

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MiEsquema' and TABLE_NAME = 'NombreTabla'
```

Para obtener todos los nombres de columna de tu esquema sería:

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MiEsquema'
```

Por tanto para cambiar los nombres de tus columnas a una tabla en específico bien podrías usar este **comando** **Update**:

```
update INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
set COLUMN_NAME = replace(COLUMN_NAME, ' ', '_')
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MiEsquema' and TABLE_NAME = 'NombreTabla';
```

Y para cambiar los nombres de columnas de todas las tablas de tu esquema sería:

```
update INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
set COLUMN_NAME = replace(COLUMN_NAME, ' ', '_')
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MiEsquema';
```

En ambos **comandos** **Update** se cambia el nombre de las columnas usando la **función replace**, la misma recibe **3** parámetros: el valor original, el texto que queremos reemplazar dentro del valor original y el nuevo valor. En este caso reemplazamos por cada nombre de columna los espacios por el guión bajo.